# Why is it so important to gather data from inside tornadoes?

Tags: meteorology, severe-weather

Or, in other words, what kind of data can be gathered from inside tornadoes and how could it help in predicting them? Also, why isn't it possible to predict/estimate this kind of data from readings taken from outside the funnel (or is that what is currently done)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, the types of data gathered outside a tornado can also be measured inside the tornado. Currently, forecasters try to estimate an area where tornadoes usually are. The forecasting time for tornadoes, or warn time, is about [13 minutes](http://www.theatlantic.com/technology/archive/2014/04/13-minutes-thats-the-average-warning-time-before-a-tornado-strikes/361195/). There is still quite a bit we don't know about tornadoes, such as why some storms that look like they can produce a tornado, will not produce a tornado.

Currently, most data taken about tornadoes is taken outside of the tornado. Data from inside the tornado, while uncommon, can give improved estimates of wind speeds, and pressure changes, with a level of detail that is hard to get from the outside, looking in. The models we deal with are imperfect- there are too many sources of error and It generally doesn't help the current predictions, but research on that data may help future predictions.